# C# cast derived class to base via serialization

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization

I was trying to find a best approach how can I cast derived class to a base class, without manually assigning properties. I though about serialization and here is what I came up with.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    ...

    public string MyProperty30 { get; set; }
}


public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public string ChildClass1 { get; set; }
    public string ChildClass2 { get; set; }

    public BaseClass ToBaseClass()
    {
        return this.ToJSON().FromJsonTo<BaseClass>();
    }
}
```

Where .ToJSON() .FromJsonTo is serialization handled with NewtonSoft JSON.NET libraries.

Do you think could be a good approach?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Why do you want to cast the class into it's base class? This all sounds a bit strange. If you can elaborate a bit it will be easier for us all to help you out.

Comment: No, this is bad approach. Better would be to use AutoMapper

Comment: Serialize-deserialize combo is a way to achieve instance copying. If you simply need deep copy, then sure this is a way. Why would you want to get base class instance as a result is unclear.

Comment: I have a base class with a bunch of properties that I need to work with and API call, which sends me all properties of BaseClass plus some additional properties that are not related to BaseClass. Data comes as JSON to my MVC WebApi. I've created a ChildClass as a ViewModel and defined all additional properties (that are not related to Bas) there